# Rasa Message object

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu

I want to run the following code that I got from:
[rasa entity extraction github](https://github.com/ESCdeGmbH/rasa-custom-entity-extraction/blob/master/simple_entity_extractor.py)

```
class SimpleEntityExtractor(EntityExtractor):
"""
This is a custom entity extractor accessing a simple JSON file that contains a dictionary of entitie groups.
This class performs (fuzzy-)matching of an input against every known list entity. The most similar entities
are returned as entities.
"""

name = "SimpleEntityExtractor"
provides = ["entities"]
requires = ["tokens"]

def __init__(self, parameters: Dict[Text, Text]) -> None:
    super(SimpleEntityExtractor, self).__init__(parameters)

    if parameters is None:
        raise AttributeError("No valid config given!")
    if not isinstance(parameters, dict):
        raise AttributeError(f"config has type {type(parameters)}")
    if "config" not in parameters.keys():
        raise AttributeError(f"config not given: parameters contains {parameters.keys()}")

    with open(parameters["config"], encoding="utf-8-sig") as json_file:
        parsed = json.load(json_file)
    self._entities = self._load(parsed)

    self._min_confidence = 0.7 if "min_confidence" not in parameters.keys() else parameters["min_confidence"]

def process(self, message: Message, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    """
    Process an incoming message by determining the most similar (or matching) names.
    """
    extracted = self._match_entities(message)
    message.set("entities", message.get("entities", []) + extracted, add_to_output=True)

def _load(self, parsed_entities):
    entities = []
    for group in parsed_entities.keys():
        for element in parsed_entities[group].keys():
            fuzzy = FuzzySet()
            for x in [element] + parsed_entities[group][element]:
                fuzzy.add(x)

            entity = {
                "group": group,
                "canonical": element,
                "fuzzy": fuzzy
            }
            entities.append(entity)
    return entities

def _match_entities(self, message: Message):
    """
    Perform fuzzy matching on each token of the message.
    A token contains its text, its offset, its end and optionally additional data.
    """
    extracted_entities = []
    tokens = message.get("tokens")
    for token in tokens:
        for entity in self._entities:
            matches = entity["fuzzy"].get(token.text)

            if matches is None:
                continue
            for match in matches:
                if match[0] < self._min_confidence:
                    continue
                match = {
                    "start": token.start,
                    "end": token.end,
                    "value": entity["canonical"],
                    "confidence": match[0],
                    "entity": entity["group"],
                }
                extracted_entities.append(match)
    return extracted_entities
```

But I don't know the format in which to pass the message. I have my query: "catches taken by brett lee". How should I pass in proper format? Here, catches and brett lee are the entities' words that need to be returned. I can't get how to build the Message object of rasa nlu.
Please help.